# How to change date value format to YYYYMMDD format

Tags: sql, sql-server

When creating a sql backup/web viewer for some AS400 data, some of the data had to be scrubbed by hand.

In this process, the dates in the database ended up being stored as strings in 2 formates:

- `YYYYMMDD`
- `MM/DD/YYYY`

In an effort to preserve the original data, I would like to convert all of the `MM/DD/YYYY` to `YYYYMMDD`. Is there a query that would fix this? Something like:

```
SELECT commentDate from SomeTable
    IF FORMAT(commentDate) LIKE '00/00/0000'
        commentDate = FORMAT(commentDate, '00000000')
```

Comment: What db are you going to run this scrubbing SQL in?

Comment: @attila the data has already been scrubbed by employees of the company we are doing the backup for, that's how the dates ended up in 2 formats.

Comment: Are you in MySQL? PostgreSQL? MSSQL?

Comment: You will do this with string manipulation, and the string manipulaton functions are different in each SQL database product.  Please specify the product.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle MSSQL

Comment: how about storing it as an actual date instead of a character string?

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly recommend you track down whoever decided to store dates as text and give him a good beating.  You're welcome to borrow my time-travelling android, if it helps.

You're almost there.  Using MS SQL syntax:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CommentDate LIKE '[12][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(DATE, CommentDate, 112)
        WHEN CommentDate LIKE '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(DATE, CommentDate, 101)
        END
FROM
    (SELECT '20140410' AS CommentDate UNION ALL SELECT '04/10/2014') AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select convert(varchar(11),cast(CommentDate  as datetime),112)
From tableName
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32778)

This shows date in yyyymmdd format if CommentDate is a valid datetime value.

Check this link for MSSQL [date format styling](http://robbamforth.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/sql-date-formats-getdate-examples/)

Comment: Will the cast work if the user's locale is set to default to dd/mm/yyyy?